# urllib2.urlopen() returning error 500 on a particular URL with GAE

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I'm having trouble using the urllib2.urlopen on a particular URL on GAE. When I run the same code on using Eclipse, I'm able to retrieve the website data, but when I try it with a GAE implementation, I get 'Status 500 Internal Server Error'.

On the ordinary Python app, I have the following code that works fine.

```
query2 = {'ORIGIN': 'LOS','DESTINATION':'ABV', 'DAY':'23',
          'MONTHYEAR': 'JAN2012', 'RDAY': '-1', 'RMONTHYER': '-1',
          'ADULTS': '1', 'KIDS': '0', 'INFANTS': '0', 'CURRENCY': 'NGN',
          'DIRECTION': 'SEARCH', 'AGENT': '111210135256.41.138.183.192.29025'}

encoded = urllib.urlencode(query2)
url3 = 'http://www.flyaero.com/cgi-bin/airkiosk/I7/171015'
request = urllib2.urlopen(url3, encoded)

print 'RESPONSE:', request
print 'URL     :', request.geturl()

headers = request.info()
print 'DATE    :', headers['date']
print 'HEADERS :'
print '---------'
print headers

data = request.read()
print 'LENGTH  :', len(data)
print 'DATA    :'
print '---------'
print data
```

This works just fine, but with GAE, it doesn't. This is the GAE code:

```
class MainPage(webapp.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):      
        query = {'ORIGIN': 'LOS','DESTINATION':'ABV', 'DAY':'23',
                 'MONTHYEAR': 'JAN2012', 'RDAY': '-1', 'RMONTHYER': '-1',
                 'ADULTS': '1', 'KIDS': '0', 'INFANTS': '0', 'CURRENCY': 'NGN',
                 'DIRECTION': 'SEARCH', 'AGENT': '111210135256.41.138.183.192.29025'}

        urlkey = 'http://www.flyaero.com/cgi-bin/airkiosk/I7/181002i?AJ=2&LANG=EN'
        urlsearch = 'http://www.flyaero.com/cgi-bin/airkiosk/I7/171015'
        user_agent = 'Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 5.5; Windows NT)'
        header = { 'User-Agent' : user_agent }

        try:
            request = urllib2.urlopen(urlkey)
            data = request.read()
            info = request.info()
        except urllib2.URLError, e:
            print 'error code: ', e

        print 'INFO:'
        print info  
        print ''        
        print 'Old key is: ' + query['AGENT']

        print 'Agent key is  ' + query['AGENT']
        encoded = urllib.urlencode(query)
        print 'encoded data', encoded
        print ''
        print 'web data'
        print''

        try:
            request2 = urllib2.urlopen(urlsearch, encoded)
            data2 = request2.read()
            info2 = request2.info()
        except urllib2.URLError, e:
            print 'error code: ', e

        print 'INFO:'
        print info2
        print ''
        print 'DATA: '
        print data
```

There are two calls to urllib2.urlopen. The first one works, but the second one returns error 500 and the try-except block doesn't catch it.

this is the message printed out by the request.info() command

```
Status: 500 Internal Server Error
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Cache-Control: no-cache
Expires: Fri, 01 Jan 1990 00:00:00 GMT
Content-Length: 1662
```

I'm not on the develooper server, i'm developing with eclipse, and running from localhost on my system. The is the error message that appears on the brower and on eclipse console as well, this is the message:

```
    WARNING  2011-12-10 17:29:31,703 urlfetch_stub.py:405] Stripped prohibited headers from   URLFetch request: ['Host']
    WARNING  2011-12-10 17:29:33,075 urlfetch_stub.py:405] Stripped prohibited headers from      URLFetch request: ['Content-Length', 'Host']
    ERROR    2011-12-10 17:29:38,305 __init__.py:463] ApplicationError: 2 timed out
    <pre>Traceback (most recent call last):

  File &quot;C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\ext\webapp\__init__.py&quot;, line 700, in __call__

handler.get(*groups)

  File &quot;C:\Users\TIOLUWA\Documents\CODES\Elipse\FlightShop\flightshop.py&quot;, line 124, in get

    request2 = urllib2.urlopen(urlsearch, encoded)

  File &quot;C:\python25\lib\urllib2.py&quot;, line 124, in urlopen

    return _opener.open(url, data)

  File &quot;C:\python25\lib\urllib2.py&quot;, line 381, in open

    response = self._open(req, data)

  File &quot;C:\python25\lib\urllib2.py&quot;, line 399, in _open
    '_open', req)

  File &quot;C:\python25\lib\urllib2.py&quot;, line 360, in _call_chain

    result = func(*args)

  File &quot;C:\python25\lib\urllib2.py&quot;, line 1107, in http_open

    return self.do_open(httplib.HTTPConnection, req)

  File &quot;C:\python25\lib\urllib2.py&quot;, line 1080, in do_open

    r = h.getresponse()

  File &quot;C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\dist\httplib.py&quot;, line 213, in getresponse

    self._allow_truncated, self._follow_redirects)

  File &quot;C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\api\urlfetch.py&quot;, line 260, in fetch

    return rpc.get_result()

  File &quot;C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\api\apiproxy_stub_map.py&quot;, line 592, in get_result

    return self.__get_result_hook(self)

  File &quot;C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\api\urlfetch.py&quot;, line 358, in _get_fetch_result

    raise DownloadError(str(err))

    DownloadError: ApplicationError: 2 timed out
```

Comment: Well, it's presumably not a URLError then. But of course we can't know, because you haven't shown us what the error is. It'll be in the logs, or the console if you're on the development server.

Comment: @DanielRoseman i've added the error message gotten from request.info() apprently, i've also added the error message from eclipse's console, since i'm not running on the GAE server

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the exception indicates, it's failing because the outgoing HTTP request timed out. Instead of using urllib2, use [URLFetch](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/urlfetch/) directly, and pass the `deadline` argument to the `fetch` function with a longer deadline.